# Calculate Kilometers on graph

Tags: math

I have this following assignment:
"The program will read from the user the Landmarks (X,Y) of the flight destination, which is 2 round numbers. the program will calculate the flight distance assuming the starting position is (0,0). the flight price is calculated by distance - every 100km (or less) cost 50$ (Constant number). the program output will be the ticket price".

Example: "Hello, please enter your destination in two integers: 
350 2471 
The price of the flight is: 
1250 ".

How did they get to this price?
its writting that the user has entered (350, 2471). and the distance between 0,0 to 350,2471 is 2495.66 km.
how did they get this number?

Comment: The price is 1244. You probably forgot to divide by 100 the 2495KM. Anyway, you're not in the right place for these questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the underlying issue here has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Math coordinate distance between two points. 
Square Root of ( (Square of X distance) + Square of Y distance))
http://www.mathopenref.com/coorddist.html

Comment: You probably heard about [Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)?

Comment: C'mon, man.  That's high school algebra.

Comment: @duffymo you are right, but its been 5 years since i graduated. so had to refresh my memory about Pythagoras. that happans :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
distance = [(x^2)+(y^2)]^(1/2)]; //Pythagoras

price = $50 * roundup(distance/100km)
```

so for your example:

```
distance = sqrt[350^2 + 2471^2] = 2495.664441
price = 50 * roundup(24.954441) = 50 * 25 = 1250
```

Note that if you didnt start from `(x1,y1)=(0,0)` you would need to use:

```
distance = [(x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2]^(1/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me do some calculation

```
S(0,0) and P(350,2471)
Px = 350 Py = 2471
distance = sqrt(Px^2 + Py^2) // as start is (0,0)
distance = 2495,66444…
```

You said every 100km its 50$

```
cost = (distance / 100) * 50
<=>    distance / 2
=> ~ 1250
```